# Flutter iOS/Andriod where to save data for easy download/transfer

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app that logs data and saves it on your phone. 
Where is the correct place to save it, if i want to be able to easily transfer it off my phone later on?

According to the Flutter docs i would normally do something like this:

```
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
return directory.path;
```

but this returns the path of

```
/data/user/0/com.myApp.myApp_app/app_flutter
```

Which i believe can only be accessed if you are root or the app that created the file.

So where and how do i save my file so that i can find it later in a file browser

**EDIT:**Here is what i ended up doing

create file like so `File file = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/data.txt');`

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to your AndroidManifest.xml

Once the app is installed go into app info and toggle on permission for storage. I originally thought this would have been done automatically but guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing this right, but something was missing. I'm writing it out for you. It may help you. Let me know if that works.

What you can do is this :

```
String directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
File file = new File('$directory/$your_file_name_in_your_local_device');
await file.writeAsBytes(dataInBytes);
print(file.path);
```

In order to get the data in bytes, please do this:

```
var dataInBytes = await request.bodyBytes;
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: hi, my question was regrading saving the data some where else. Your solution still saves to ```/data/user/0/``` which is only accessible by root or the app

Comment: Did you try giving out the file name, and see if this saves this file in your specified directory, cos `File file = new File($dir/$file_name)` saves it to the file where you want it. What do you get when you print `file.path` @CrustyWang?

Comment: If i try this ```/storage/Download/data.txt``` i get no such file/dir exists, and if try ```/storage/emulated/0/Download/data.txt``` i get permission denied

Comment: So give data access permission to your app, in Android it is in `Manifest.xml`, and in iOS, it is in `info.plist`. Do it @CrustyWang

Comment: Ahh found out the problem was i have to manually go into app info on the phone and toggle the permission for storage, i assumed it would do it automatically or prompt me but guess not